# What's wrong with naming a rule?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, replacement

Please have a look at the code below. The second `Manipulate` uses the name `rl` of the replacement rule given in the first line, but unlike the first `Manipulte`, it does not plot anything, at least not on my computer. What goes wrong and how should I correct it? And why is `%` immune to the problem?

```
rl = {ρ -> 1 / 5 Sqrt[25 - 25 z^2 + 10 Sin[5 ϕ] + Sin[5 ϕ]^2]};
Manipulate[PolarPlot[ρ /. % // Evaluate, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], {z, -1, 1}]
Manipulate[PolarPlot[ρ /. rl // Evaluate, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], {z, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: `With[{rl = rl // Evaluate}, 
 Manipulate[PolarPlot[\[Rho] /. rl, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}], {z, -1, 1}]]` - read the documentation, understand the scoping behavior of `Manipulate`...

Comment: @ciao that doesn't explain why `%` works.

Comment: `Manipulate` is a scoping construct so the second example which is not working is behaving correctly :-) `z` defined in `rl` is different than `z` from `Manipulate's` spec part, or will be as soon as `Manipulate` is evaluated. So at the end you should use `With` as ciao showed or define a function and pass `z` and `ϕ`. This of course doesn't explain why `%` works. Maybe there are some special rules about how FrontEnd reads `%` and `Out[_]`, would be good to know.

Comment: @QuantumDot, huh? Of course it does. That causes the result of the prior line to replace the % before anything else, exactly as if it had been there directly.

Comment: @ciao but why `%` is expected to be replaced asap?

Comment: @ciao Thank you for the answer and the advice!

Comment: @Kuba Thank you! I knew of the scoping behaviour of `Manipulate` before but my understanding of it was superficial. After reading your explanation, perhaps I can say now that I have understood it almost completely.

Comment: I think this is really weird and I don't understand it at all. I can see why the `rl` version does not work.  It is because `Manipulate` is `HoldAll`, so its arguments are not evaluated immediately.  You'd think that `Evaluate` fixes this, but it doesn't because it does not appear in the first level inside `Manipulate`.  It is nested within `PolarPlot`, so it cannot override the `HoldAll` attribute of `Manipulate`.  But I cannot see any reason why the `%` version would work!!  There is something very strange going on.  *None of the 'answers' below explain the behaviour at all.*

Comment: I think that `Manipulate` itself has special support for `%`, i.e. `Out`, and expands it as a special case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This version works:

```
rl = {ρ[z_, ϕ_] :> 1/5 Sqrt[25 - 25 z^2 + 10 Sin[5 ϕ] + Sin[5 ϕ]^2]};
Manipulate[PolarPlot[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[ρ[z, ϕ], %]], {ϕ,0, 2 Pi}], {z, -1, 1}]
Manipulate[PolarPlot[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[ρ[z, ϕ], rl]], {ϕ,0, 2 Pi}], {z, -1, 1}]
```

The main change is in the way the rule is defined as a $RuleDelayed$ instead of $Rule$.

Comment: Thank you! I did try RuleDelayed but my attempt was in vain. Your code tells me why my code didn't work: I did not write rho as a function.

Comment: It's not a function per se, but a pattern. 
A function is similar to this but applies the rule whenever the pattern is encoutered.
Happy to help

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to ciao's and Kuba's explanation, I have thought of some little code to exemplify the scoping behaviour of `Manipulate`; I hope it will be helpful to people who are still not very familiar with the concept:

a),

```
Manipulate[Hold@x, {x,0,1}]
```

b),

```
p=x;
Manipulate[2 p-x,{x,0,1}]
```

c),

```
rpl=q->x;
Manipulate[(2 q/.rpl)-x,{x,0,1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Others have explained why the version with `rl` does not work.  But this does not explain the very weird phenomenon that the version with `%` does work.  Why is `%` (which is just a notation for [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html)) special?

It seems that `Manipulate` singles out `Out` (i.e. `%`) for special treatment.  Observe:

```
In[1]:= x
Out[1]= x

In[2]:= Manipulate[Hold[%1], {x, 0, 1}]
Out[2]= Manipulate[Hold[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

`Manipulate` has taken the `Out[1]` (same as `%1`), and evaluated it, even though it was inside of `Hold`.  This is not normal evaluation. It is `Manipulate` looking specifically for `%` and replacing it with its value.

---

This is no doubt done to make Mathematica less confusing and more accessible to beginners.  But personally I don't like this special behaviour at all.  For people who already understand how Mathematica works this (undocumented!) behaviour is very surprising and completely unexpected.

Comment: Yes I find this very confusing.  I think I fall somewhere between "beginner" and "experienced", and I find weird nuances in *Mathematica* like these only serve to confuse people like me.  I really wish they implemented a global switch that turned off all "noob" features to make *Mathematica* behave more regularly.

Comment: Also, I think that Wolfram Research ought to clearly document the evaluation sequences inside `Manipulate`, `Animate` and other functions that are as complex and as, so to speak, mysterious.